# Why Regex is not Working? for [^#]

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I need a regex that matches the below link patterns as follows.

1. `'https://website/1/extension1'` -> `True`
2. `'https://website/1.1/extension1'` -> `False`
3. `'https://website/1/#extension1'` -> `False`

My regex is

```
regex = re.compile('https://website/1[^\.]/*[^#]')
```

It works find for the case two. But I wonder why this doesn't return `False` in case of occurrence of `#` in link.

Comment: Because `https://docs.python.org/3/` matches your expression. It doesn't matter there are more characters beyond that point.

Comment: Also, you are matching zero or more `/` slashes there, is that what you wanted?

Comment: I want to skip all links containing '#' and the links like https://website/1.1/something or https://website/1.2/something.html

Comment: Are you looking for [`re.compile('https://website/\d+/\w+')`](https://regex101.com/r/3pb9J8/1) ?

Comment: Not exactly, I want to search website with 1 digit only /d+ will allow all integers. Similarly, I just want to avoid links ending with named anchors like 'http://....#something'

Comment: `\d` allows for a single integer, *just drop the quantifier*.

Comment: You oversimplified your examples. Actual Python documentation links have more path segments after the `version/` section. You now have a wrong answer below because they only match the `#` in *one* location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex matches the `https://website/1/` prefix, and nothing more. It doesn't matter that the string contains more text beyond that `/` after the version number.

You need to include *anchors*, to make sure you are not just matching a substring. Use `^` and `$` to anchor to the start and end of a string, so there is no room left for other strings. You need to match paths that don't include any `#` characters:

```
^https://docs\.python\.org/\d/[^#]*$
```

I also escaped the dots in the hostname, you don't want to match 'any' character, you want to match literal `'.'` characters. `\d` matches one digit (so `2` and `3` for major Python versions, but no more).

Online demo: https://regex101.com/r/gL7X7o/3

Python demo using Python documentation URLs:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'^https://docs\.python\.org/3/[^#]*$')
>>> links = [
...     'https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax',
...     'https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html',
...     'https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html',
...     'https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html',
... ]
>>> for link in links:
...     print('{!r} -> {}'.format(link, bool(pattern.search(link)))
...
'https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax' -> False
'https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html' -> True
'https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html' -> False
'https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html' -> True
```